# Code refactoring of 2 duplicate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, refactoring, nsmutablearray

Basically I have 2 methods that are similar in functionality. The only difference is the class container that are different. What I am trying to achieve is to unify these 2 methods and somehow have the container be dynamic.

here are the 2 methods:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) parseRequest:(NSArray*)elements {
    NSMutableArray *currentStruct = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id element elemets) {
        // This is where the difference is
        FriendRequest *friend = [[FriendRequest alloc] init];

        if(nickname != nil) {
            friend.nickname = [element objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        [currentStruct addObject:friend];   
        [friend release];

    }
    return currentStruct;
}
```

Second:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) parseRequest:(NSArray*)elements {
    NSMutableArray *currentStruct = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id element elemets) {
        // This is where the difference is
        Friend *friend = [[Friend alloc] init];

        if(nickname != nil) {
            friend.nickname = [element objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        [currentStruct addObject:friend];   
        [friend release];

    }
    return currentStruct;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that class a parameter.

```
-(NSMutableArray*) parseRequest:(NSArray*)elements withClass:(Class)friendClass {
    NSMutableArray *currentStruct = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id element elemets) {
        // This is where the difference is
        id friend = [[friendClass alloc] init];  // <---

        if(nickname != nil) {
            [friend setNickname:[element objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
        [currentStruct addObject:friend];   
        [friend release];

    }
    return currentStruct;
}

...

-(NSMutableArray*) parseRequest:(NSArray*)elements {
  return [self parseRequest:elements withClass:[Friend class]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the factory pattern:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) parseRequest:(NSArray*)elements factory:(SEL)factory {
    NSMutableArray *currentStruct = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id element elemets) {
        NSObject *friend = [self performSelector:factory];

        if(nickname != nil) {
            [friend performSelector:@selector(setNickname) withObject:[element objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
        [currentStruct addObject:friend];

    }
    return currentStruct;
}

-(Friend*) friendFactory {
    return [[[Friend alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```